# Flatten subselect rows for WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

I have a table of customers in which there are 3 columns for ids for different accounts, like this:

```
customers: id, account1_id, account2_id, account3_id
```

Now, I need to select ids from all those columns for use in WHERE part of another query, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM balances
WHERE account_id IN (
    SELECT account1_id, account2_id, account3_id FROM customers
)
```

Of course it doesn't work because it returns something like 2-dimentional array and I need 1-dimentional one.
I tried to use:

```
WHERE (`account_id`, `account_id`, `account_id`) IN (
    SELECT account1_id, account2_id, account3_id FROM customers
)
```

but it ANDs account_id and I need ORs. Also tried:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',' account1_id, account2_id, account3_id) AS accounts FROM customers
```

but that it doesn't work too as I had to search inside returned strings.

I tried to use REGEXP but couldn't get right syntax with subselect and also I'm not convinced it would be efficient.

So, how do I flatten that 2d array into 1d one?

Comment: *a table of customers in which there are 3 columns for ids for different accounts, like this* Normalize it. For example, to `(id, account_id, account_number)`.

Comment: omg, how I'd like to! But it's legacy DB and of course it's untouchable :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT balances.* 
FROM balances
JOIN customers ON balances.account_id IN ( customers.account1_id, 
                                           customers.account2_id, 
                                           customers.account3_id )
```

or the same with WHERE EXISTS.